# How to center RecyclerView items horizontally with vertical GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` using a `GridLayoutManager`. I want each column to be centered, but the columns begin all the way on the left. In the following picture you can see what I'm talking about. I used the ugly color scheme to illustrate the columns and background. The green is the background for each item in the `RecyclerView`, the red is the background of the `RecyclerView` itself:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGGTY.jpg

I'm setting it up with:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

Here's the column_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="120dp"
              android:layout_height="180dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_column_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_column_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the recyclerview xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/company_details_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Try letting the column item fill the width of the column while centering everything inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="180dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_column_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_column_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Item with filled width solved the issue to me! thanks

Comment: Also, if you have another nested cointainer like a constraintLayout that should use android:layout_width="match_parent" to keep the same

Comment: What if I want to column item height to fill screen?

Answer (score 3):

***To restate** @kris larson's answer;*

If you are using `ConstraintLayout`, adding `android:layout_gravity="center"` or `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` to the parent layout in item's `XML` would be enough (the first parent in hierarchy).

In your case, the codes would be something **similar** to this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/movie_column_photo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_column_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Simply set the width of the root layout for your `column_item.xml` to `match_parent` will center RecyclerView items horizontally.

Answer (score -4):

Wrap your recyclerview inside the constraintlayout, something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/book_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:spanCount="2" />
```

Hope it helps!!